# Laravel - ERROR: Trying to get property 'depthead' of non-object

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 blade that has this code:

```
@foreach($employees as $key => $employee)
               <li class="list-group-item">
                 <b>Line Manager:</b> 
                 @if(!$employee->linemanager)
                  <a class="float-right">N/A</a>
                 @else
                 <a class="float-right">{{ $employee->linemanager->fullName() ?? 'None' }}</a>
                 @endif
               </li>  
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <b>HOD:</b> 
                 @if(!$employee->department->depthead)
                  <a class="float-right">N/A</a>
                 @else
                 <a class="float-right">{{isset($employee->department->depthead) ? $employee->department->depthead->first_name. ' ' .$employee->department->depthead->last_name : 'None'}}</a>
                 @endif                                        
              </li>  

@endforeach
```

and its pointing to this line:

> @if(!$employee->department->depthead)

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Provide your controller  and model code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of your issue is that `$employee->department` is either `null` or not an `Object` (Instance of `Department`, assuming you have Model and Relationships setup properly). You've got a check in place, but it's in the wrong spot. Check for `$employee->department` and `$employee->department->depthead`:

```
@if($employee->department)
  @if($employee->department->depthead)
    {{ $employee->department->depthead->first_name. ' ' .$employee->department->depthead->last_name }}
  @else
    None
  @endif
@else
  N/A
@endif
```

The defaults returned from a properly formed relationship will remove the need for string checks, meaning that `@if($employee->department)` and `@if($employee->department->depthead)` will be "truthy" or "falsey" enough to handle your use case.

Sidenote, this complexity is best moved to a `Model` function. In your `Employee` model, add this function:

```
public function getDepartmentHeadAttribute(){
  if ($this->department) {
    if ($this->department->depthead) {
      return "{$this->department->depthead->first_name} {$this->department->depthead->last_name}";
    } else {
      return 'None';
    }
  } else {
    return 'N/A';
  }
}
```

Then, in your `.blade.php` file, you can simply do:

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
  {{ $employee->department_head }}
@endforeach
```

And it will perform the required if checks inside your Model and output First/Last, None or N/A as requird.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(!$employee->department->depthead)
```

look like the employee->department is not null, but it is not an object too ...
may be it is a string or number ....

```
@if(!$employee->department->depthead)
```

you could use  'is_object' method to determine that ...

```
@if( is_object($employee->department))
@if(!$employee->department->depthead)
....
@endIf
@endIf
```

but i don't think that the problem ...
the problem maybe  you miss loading the relation,
if the property 'department' is a field of type 'json'
don't forget to cast it in model to 'array'